# DRF nested serializers convert a table to a structured json

Tags: python, mysql, json, django-rest-framework

Say, I have a MySQL table like:

```
| model_id | feature_name | feature_value | count | woe  | iv   |
| -------- | ------------ | ------------- | ----- | ---- | ---- |
| 1        | age          | age0          | 200   | 0.34 | 0.22 |
| 1        | age          | age1          | 300   | 0.22 | 0.34 |
| 1        | sex          | 0             | 250   | 0.38 | 0.03 |
| 1        | sex          | 1             | 250   | 0.48 | 0.21 |
| ...      |              |               |       |      |      |
```

and I want to response a json result like this(`value_count` is the feature's value count and `total_iv` is the sum of the feature's value iv):

```
{
    model_id: 1,
    feature:[
        {
            name: "age",
            value_count: 2,
            total_iv: 0.56,
            data: [
                {
                    value: 'age0',
                    count: 200,
                    woe: 0.34,
                    iv, 0.22
                },
                {
                    value: 'age1',
                    count: 300,
                    woe: 0.22,
                    iv, 0.34
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "sex",
            value_count: 2,
            total_iv: 0.24,
            data: [
                {
                    value: '0',
                    count: 250,
                    woe: 0.38,
                    iv, 0.03
                },
                {
                    value: 'age1',
                    count: 250,
                    woe: 0.48,
                    iv, 0.21
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I thought should use [nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).

The client would use model_id to retrieve this result, but there were two questions to be solved:

1. Should I redesign my SQL table to fit my json structure?
2. How to get values from nested serializer cause I want to calculate the total value?

Any suggestions are welcome!